# Django: html button referencing a foreign key

Tags: python, html, django

i'm quite new to Django and i'm stuck on foreignkeys here. I have seen multiple tutorials and read a lot of questions on here but i didn't really find an answer :/

So to explain the context: I have  2 models:

```
class example(models.Model):
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    a = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    b = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

```
class addexample(models.Model):
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
    id = models.ForeignKey(Example, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    c = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

this is my **example.html**

```
        {% for item in example %}   
            <tr>                    
            <td>{{ item.a }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.b }}</td>
            <td>
               <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/example2" role="button">Link</a>
            </td>
            </tr>

            {% endfor %
```

So in my table there is a button that refers to a certain database id. So how do i proceed in my views.py? in other words if i click the button and go to that "subform" where i can add addiditions (in this case this means addexample.c). How would I retrieve the Foreign key of the button from the line that I just pushed?

I know how to request the user_id but how do I request that ForeignKey of that button?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: which foreign key are you trying to get?

Comment: I'm trying to get the foreignkey from the "Example" model. They are relate to eachother.
You can think of Example being the parent and Example2 as the child that you want to add through that button.

Comment: So you want the primary key value of the Example model that is the foreign key of the addexample model?

Comment: yes, exactly :)

Comment: ok and it is only in your example.html that after you click the link you go to another form to create an addexample object?

Comment: yes indeed, you click the button and a new page is loaded (preferably without some type of key in the url for security reasons) with a form that resembles the addexample class. I might do it in a modal or something else later on. But i can probably figure that out by myself if i know how to do it with a new page.

Answer (score 0):

Try using item.pk, this should be what is being referenced by the foreign key. You could add this value to the route of your button so it is a known value on the next page, for example make the route /example2/{item.pk}

Comment: sure but if i safe the form on my example2.html how can i retrieve that key?

Answer (score 0):

I am new to django too,I assumed you already created an url and view for your first module(example), try this in urls.py (URL for when the user press your button)

```
urlpatterns=[
path('addexample/<int:cats>/', Add, name= 'ADD'),
]
```

on example.html change the button to

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href=""{% url 'ADD' example.user%}"" role="button">Link</a>
```

on views.py(to connect the module with the html)

```
def Add(request,cats):
    context ={
        'cats':cats,
        'all':example.objects.filter(user=cats)
    }

    return render(request,'new.html',context)
```

Now you need to create a new.html which will contain the page which the button will transfer to and you can point the previous page forignkey by variable(cats) and the module for that exact key by variable (all)

I hope I helped you

Comment: and so i can retrieve the same variable when i submit the form on example2/.....html?